# Jquery show image while .show()

Tags: jquery, show

I got a big table that I want to show up when I click on a button.

Here's the code, no big deal so far:

```
$(".show_table_button").on("click", function() {
    $('#load').css('visibility', 'visible');
    $("#my_table").show();
    // Commented $('#load').css('visibility', 'hidden');
});
```

My problem is that #my_table has a lot of data and it takes a moment to show up so I wanted to show a loading image meanwhile, but this code doesn't work.
The loading image (#load) only appears after the table (#my_table) is shown...

Any idea that could help?

Comment: Post the HTML that goes with this as well. There's not enough information here to present you with a solution.

Comment: If there is an AJAX call you should post that code too

Comment: @TonySamperi There isn't, the table and all its data are already on the file when I click on the "Show table" button. But there's a lot of data on the table and somehow it takes a few seconds to show it up...

Comment: Ok, in this case you could use an event to handle the spinner...

Answer (score 0):

I'd do:

```
 $('#load').fadeIn(0, function() {
    $("#my_table").fadeIn(200, function() { 
        $('#load').hide(); 
    });
 });
```

Which is showing the loader and then showing the table within 200 milliseconds and then hide the loader.

Answer (score 0):

Spinner.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var spinner = $('#load');
    $(window).on("showSpinner", function(){
         spinner.fadeIn();
    });
    $(window).on("hideSpinner", function(){
         spinner.fadeOut();
    });
});
```

HTML:
Since you already have all the html in the page, put a custom attribute on the last row.

```
<tr last-row>Your content</tr>
```

Your JS

```
var tableComplete = false;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#my_table tr[last-row]").on("load", function(){
        tableComplete = true;
    });
$(".show_table_button").on("click", function() {
    if(tableComplete){
        $("#my_table").fadeIn();
    }
    else{
        $(window).trigger("showSpinner");
        $("#my_table tr[last-row]").off("load").on("load", function(){
            tableComplete = true;
            $(window).trigger("hideSpinner");
            $("#my_table").fadeIn();
        });
    }

});
```